# What is the correct way to use UTF-8 characters with PostgreSQL and Ruby Object Mapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, utf-8, ruby-object-mapper

I've tried many random shots in the dark, such as:

```
  config.gateways[:default] = [:sql, database_url, encoding: 'UTF8']
```

And all variations on UTF8, e.g., utf8, utf-8, unicode, Unicode.

- I've tried setting the shell env's LC_CTYPE to UTF8.
- I've tried setting the client_encoding parameter on the connection URL.
- I've verified that the database has an encoding of UTF8, i.e., `SHOW server_encoding`.
- I've verified that ROM's Sequel connection reports a client encoding of
  UTF8 right before actual use, i.e., `SHOW client_encoding`;
- I've verified that I can insert and read back UTF-8 characters with the same database using psql.
- I've verified I can insert and read back UTF-8 characters with the same database using Rails' ActiveRecord.

But when I give ROM non-ASCII, UTF-8 characters to insert, the characters are replaced with '�' somewhere along the way to PostgreSQL.

What is the correct way to setup ROM and use it with UTF-8 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm we pass connection options straight to Sequel, then if you specify during connection configuration option like encoding: utf-8 it will work

`ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, "postgres://...", { encoding: utf-8 })`

```
require 'rom'
require 'rom-sql'

DATABASE_URL = ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', 'postgres://localhost/rom')
setup = ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, DATABASE_URL, encoding: 'unicode')
rom = ROM.container(setup)

conn = setup.default.connection
conn.drop_table?(:users)
conn.create_table :users do
  String :name
end

class Users < ROM::Relation[:sql]
end

setup.register_relation(:users)

rom.relations.users.insert(:name => "Pöter")

p rom.relations.users.to_a
```

Comment: Thanks, at least I know it works for someone! While this doesn't work for us, I'll mark it as accepted as I'm sure it is the right way.